# Circular base class dependency error in autogenerated code of the added service reference

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, .net-4.6.1

I created a WCF web service that I want to consume. On my client, I added a new service reference. It finds it, I give it a namespace and click OK. It generates the appropriate code, but when I rebuild the app, I get an error:

```
Circular base class dependency involving 'WSHelperClient' and 'WSHelperClient'
```

Here is the autogenerated code. If I replace "WSHelperClient.WSHelper." with "", it fixes the Circular base class dependency error.

Anyone knows why the autogenerated code is not compiling and I need to change it manually?

```
namespace WSHelperClient.WSHelper {
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System;


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="PowerShellResponse", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WSHelper")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class PowerShellResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string DescriptionField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool HadErrorsField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Description {
        get {
            return this.DescriptionField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DescriptionField, value) != true)) {
                this.DescriptionField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool HadErrors {
        get {
            return this.HadErrorsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.HadErrorsField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.HadErrorsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("HadErrors");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="WSHelper.IWSHelper")]
public interface IWSHelper {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/ConvertUserMailboxToShared", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/ConvertUserMailboxToSharedResponse")]
    WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse ConvertUserMailboxToShared(string email);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/ConvertUserMailboxToShared", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/ConvertUserMailboxToSharedResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> ConvertUserMailboxToSharedAsync(string email);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveUserLicences", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveUserLicencesResponse")]
    WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse RemoveUserLicences(string upn);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveUserLicences", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveUserLicencesResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> RemoveUserLicencesAsync(string upn);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveMailboxFromAddressBook", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveMailboxFromAddressBookResponse")]
    WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse RemoveMailboxFromAddressBook(string email);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveMailboxFromAddressBook", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IWSHelper/RemoveMailboxFromAddressBookResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> RemoveMailboxFromAddressBookAsync(string email);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IWSHelperChannel : WSHelperClient.WSHelper.IWSHelper, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class WSHelperClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.IWSHelper>, WSHelperClient.WSHelper.IWSHelper {

    public WSHelperClient() {
    }

    public WSHelperClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public WSHelperClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public WSHelperClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public WSHelperClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse ConvertUserMailboxToShared(string email) {
        return base.Channel.ConvertUserMailboxToShared(email);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> ConvertUserMailboxToSharedAsync(string email) {
        return base.Channel.ConvertUserMailboxToSharedAsync(email);
    }

    public WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse RemoveUserLicences(string upn) {
        return base.Channel.RemoveUserLicences(upn);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> RemoveUserLicencesAsync(string upn) {
        return base.Channel.RemoveUserLicencesAsync(upn);
    }

    public WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse RemoveMailboxFromAddressBook(string email) {
        return base.Channel.RemoveMailboxFromAddressBook(email);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<WSHelperClient.WSHelper.PowerShellResponse> RemoveMailboxFromAddressBookAsync(string email) {
        return base.Channel.RemoveMailboxFromAddressBookAsync(email);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I named my project WSHelperClient and that conflicted with the service code. So I called my client WSHelperWindowsClient and it solve the problem.